# Pairwise comparison array Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, compare, pairwise

I 'm trying to compare if two consecutive elements of an array are equal.

I have tried using for but as it returns a boolean but it does not seem to work what am I missing

```
val array1 = Array(1, 4, 2, 3)

def equalElements(array : Array[Int]) : Boolean = {
  
  for (i <- 1 to  (array.size )) {
    if (array(i) == array(i + 1)) true else false
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in scala zero based.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but `if (booleanCheck) true else false` can just be written as `booleanCheck` since that expression returns a Boolean anyway.

Comment: You are not returning anything.

Comment: even If when I store the result of if expression it shows the unit error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sliding` that

> Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window"
> over them (as opposed to partitioning them, as is done in grouped.)

```scala
val array1 = Array(1, 1, 2, 2)
val equalElements = array1
  .sliding(size = 2, step = 1) //step = 1 is a default value.
  .exists(window => window.length == 2 && window(0) == window(1))
```